# Google app engine dev_appserver.py, how to ensure all transactions are written in go111

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I am using dev_appserver.py to develop locally for the GAE in the go111 runtime.
I'd like to ensure all the transactions are written on the disk, in the dev_appserver.py it happens when you shutdown it.

In particular the python code in the `./platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/stub_util.py` file of the Google cloud SDK one can see:

```
def cleanup_stubs():
  """Do any necessary stub cleanup e.g. saving data."""
  # Saving datastore
  logging.info('Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore')
  datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')
  datastore_stub.Write()
```

I similarly need to ensure all past transactions are written properly written, is it possible to have a similar effect from golang?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure on what your issue consist on. From my understanding you are using the dev_appserver.py server on the go111 GAE runtime but the transactions to Datastore  are not written on the disk? Could you share the code you are using to save those transactions?

Comment: What you said shows you understand.

About the code just imagine calling repeatedly `datastore.PutMulti` to put for example 1100 entities in batches of 500 (the maximum the GAE accepts in one shot) and just after do a query to get all entities. Instead of 1100 entities you'll get fewer. But, if between the writing and reading you shutdown the dev_appserver.py then you'll get all 1100 entities as expected. Is there a way to ensure all data are written?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#emulator_data_directories), the data persist between sessions. So as long as you mantain the `local_db.bin` undeleted, those records are written in this file. But this is a binary file so won't be able to open the file with a text editor and check if the data is there.